# How do I import a class with a different venv?

Tags: python

I am working on a Django project and I wanted to re-use a class from another project.
Both projects have their own virtual environment (made with `python -m venv`)

Is there a way to import the class without bringing in all its requirements within the project?

Structure:

```
MyDjangoProject/
   .venv
    main/
        views.py

MyClass/
   .venv
    main/
        views.py
```

And, on a separate note, considering that `MyClass` and `MyDjangoProject` are two different repositories, how do I import with relative paths?

Comment: Don't view your code in terms of repositories. Repositories are just where you keep code for source-control purposes, and a virtual environment should never be part of a repository. For actually *running* code, you create a virtual environment in which you *install* all necessary code.

Comment: Completely agree with you there! Repositories are for me a way to keep my codebase tidy (and .```venv```'s are in the ```.gitignore```). So basically you're saying that I should just insert the Class requirements into the main django ones for the venv installations?

Comment: I'm saying you should have a way to install `MyClass` as a package (write an appropriate `MyClass/setup.py`, e.g.), then run something like `MyDjangoProject/.venv/bin/pip install MyClass`.

Comment: Ok never done it, seems like a good time as any to learn.
Thanks! I'm new to python, I am more of a C++ guy

Comment: Depending on how extensive `MyClass` is, the class you actually want may need to be pulled out into its own package that both `MyClass` and `MyDjangoProject` can each install.

Comment: you should treat MyClass as a library. here's a link to get you up and running https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-python-library-7d5aea80cc3f